# Is the range of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ closed or open or neither?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of a metric space $X$ and $E$ be its range.
Is $E$ closed or open in $X$ or neither?

Comment: Does this sequence have an accumulating point? If we take that $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ than set $\{x_n\}$ is not closed nor open, but if we take $x_n=n$ it is closed.

Comment: @Poppy:Is accumulating point equal to limit point?

Comment: It doesn't have to be. Limit point is an accumulating point, but not the other way around. For example, sequence $(-1)^n$ has two accumulating points: -1 and 1

Comment: @Poppy:I means the range of {xn}, not {xn} itself. So range of{1/n} may be the union of {xn} and {0}, is that right?

Comment: Range of $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ does not include $0$. If that is what you asked. But this fact has nothing to do with my example.

Comment: There is a difference between an accumulating point of a sequence and a set. Are you familiar with it? My fist question was not precise enough: "Does this sequence have an accumulating point?".

Comment: @Poppy: Not familiar with accumulating point, actually. Can you tell me its definition?

Comment: Ok, the right term is 'accumulation point'. Metric spaces should come after calculus...

Comment: @Poppy: An accumulation point is a point which is the limit of a sequence, is that right?

Comment: An accumulation point of a sequence is a point whose every neighborhood contains infinitely many members of that sequence. If a sequce has a limit, it has only one accumulation point. But sequences can have a lot of accumulation points and then they are not convergent, of course.

Comment: @Poppy:"An accumulation point of a sequence"? Do there exist an accumulation point of a metric space or something else?

Comment: I know about accumulation point of a sequence and a set. But, a sequence can be in a metric space, in a topological space,... We can talk about a sequence of numbers, functions, operators,... The definition I gave you is right for topological spaces (therefore also for metric spaces) and it is irrelevant if we are talking about numbers or functions or anything else. You should only know what is a neighborhood in your space.

Comment: @Poppy: Ok, make sense. Thanks^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the sequence:

Consider any sequence of all rational numbers in the metric space $\mathbb{R}$ (one can make such a sequence because the rationals form a countable set). Then the range of this sequence is not closed; the closure of the range is equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand, consider the sequence $a_n = 0$ (for all $n$) in $\mathbb{R}$. Then the range of the sequence is $\{ 0 \}$, a closed set.